setAdapter(new adapter(insert())); and context connectting
I am on trying to saving checkbox value to be saved. and i typed the 'Context', it has problem with setAdapter on my mainactivity java. how can i solve this problem?
setAdapter insert () on my main activity and 'Context' on my adapter seem to be unable to be co-exist. how can i solve this problem?
i tried to remove the 'Context context' in Adapter but i think it needs for SQLitedata saving.
<My main Activity.java>

public class beginner_n_use extends AppCompatActivity {
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<kr_style> krlist;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rc_view);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new n_adapter(insertlist())); 
                                       ** *? (((((<- Here insertlist has problem with adapter)))))**


}


ArrayList insertlist() {
    krlist = new ArrayList<>();
    kr_style list1 = new kr_style("A");
    kr_style list2 = new kr_style("B");
    kr_style list3 = new kr_style("C");
    kr_style list4 = new kr_style("D");

<My Adapter>

public class n_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<n_adapter.ViewHolder> {
private final ArrayList<kr_style> krlist;
private Intent intent;

private Context context;
private cbDB cbDB;

public n_adapter(ArrayList<kr_style> krlist, Context context) { 
                            *? (((((<- when this Context exist, setAdapter insert has problem. ))))) 
this.krlist = krlist; this.context = context; }


